# Is there a faster way to call a receiver than on boot completed?

Tags: android

some context:
I have an alarm app I use for myself that locks the screen when the alarm goes off for the duration you request prior. Essentially your phone is a ringing brick for x minutes. The only problem is my sleepy self is very irrational and in the morning I figured out that if I turn off the phone and get to the app location and uninstall it before the receiver gets called (boot completed) then I can bypass it bricking my phone. This didn't use to be a big deal when my LG G2 was on 4.2.2 because of how fast the receiver was called I would usually have to restart my phone about 5-8 times to uninstall the app before it was bricked so I just gave up and quit trying. Now, I upgraded to 4.4.2 and the receiver is called about a full 10 seconds later letting me delete the app on the first try every time. Making the app completely useless.

What I have tried:
I have tried using quick_boot in the manifest but I believe that this is only for HTC because on_boot doesn't get called for that OS for some reason. I have also tried the user present which only seems to work after the boot is completed when doing things like unlocking your phone.

Is there really no way to make onReceive be called quicker than onBoot? It would make sense if there isn't , I'm just hoping someone could provide a definite answer either way.

Comment: There isn't a faster way, this is the first notification that Android sends out that a boot is completed. The reason it is likely slower now is that Google has actually implemented security features to keep you from being able to do pretty much exactly what your app is designed to do :P

Comment: This question is a bit like..."Is it possible to drive my car before I've started the engine?"

Comment: Based on your description of the problem, you should file a bug against the *user*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have answered this a week or so after I asked this question because I found a pretty useful workaround, although, it is a little sloppy.

I made a new activity(homeLock) with the intent filter .  homeLock extends activity and my old main activity(alarmMain) extends homeLock now instead of activity. All homeLock does is start the overlay service(so you can't stop the alarm/use the phone) that will be turned off by alarmMain when it determines whether an alarm should be ringing currently or not. In alarmMain there is a button now that says "change home" which lets you make homeLock the home application. Now, when you turn off the phone and restart to try and delete the application before onBootReceived is called which starts the broadcast receiver(triggers alarm and overlay) the homeLock activity is called which puts an overlay on the screen until it can be removed after the application determines if an alarm should be playing or not (after onBootReceived).

Basically, before you go to sleep just set this application as your home application from within the app or through settings. Now, it should be impossible to delete the application or turn off the alarm once it has started ringing until it has rung its duration because there will always be an overlay on the screen even when restarting the phone.

Obviously this addition is only needed for phones that boot slowly or extremely degenerate sleepers, or both like me. While it is unlikely this will help anyone because it is such a unique problem I thought I should post the workaround I have been using just in case someone does end up finding it useful.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it is. I'm not 100% sure but i think (some) systemapps have higher priority then the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED event. AND there is ACTION_SCREEN_ON which should be triggered before ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.

Comment: Emanuel, I should have mentioned I did try ACTION_SCREEN_ON as well and boot_completed still seemed to be first.